# Unwanted blank lines in my Python function output

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a data science project to make some prediction, and I need to calculate a new column based on other column values.

All is working fine, except that my Jupyter-lab is printing me blank lines in my output and I don't know why.

Here's the code :

```
# Calcul A :
pas = 1500
TailleTotal = len(df)
limite=TailleTotal-pas

df['A'] = np.empty(TailleTotal, dtype = float)
index=0
while index < limite :
    A_temp = 0
    A_temp = np.sqrt((df['X'][index]**2)+(df['Y'][index]**2)+(df['Z'][index]**2))
    df['A'][index]=A_temp
    index = index+1
```

And when I run it, I have a blank line for every iteration.. My files is making more than 1M lines, I have to scroll all over in my code it's very annoying.

But it's more that I really don't understand why it does this, I have no print function or anything that is supposed to show me something.. So why Python have this need to show me empty lines ? It's because I have no "return" in my loop ?

Edit : It appears to be a "output memory" problem from Jupyter-lab. Right clicking and "clear all output" is resolving my issue

Comment: Sooo I didn't change anything and now it has stopped to make me these blank line.

I really don't understand. Maybe a memory problem in Python ?

A strange thing is that my .ipynb files were going from 10/20kb~ to 15/20mb~

Comment: Output memory was the problem, clearing the output by right click "clear all output" resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop, first change the while and try to do maybe 1 or 2 iterations and check if the problem is the same. I'm prety sure that dissapears. The kernel should be consuming resources for your loop.

Comment: No it's not infinite, it stop when index is superior to limit (~1500 line before the end, defined by "pas" variable).
It actually do the job very well, creating my "A" column and filling it with the right calculation.
It's more about the output showing blank line but I didn't ask for nothing.